# How to run a list of below given linux commands in single file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, command

I need to the below commands one after the other each time manually, how to put all these below commands in a single shot :

> 1. connect to a server **[need to give password, port number , ip etc.]**
> 2. Login by giving username.**(just username)**
> 3. Entering password for the above user.**(just password)**
> 4. Now logging in from this server to another server. **(ssh username@IP)**
> 5. Entering username & password for the new server.**(just username & password)**
> 6. Executing command to connect to mysql in the current server. (**mysql -u username -p --socket=/data/mysql/mysql.sock)**
> 7. Entering mysql password.**(just password)**

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it as follow:

```
ssh -t -t -Lport:localhost:port login@server1 'ssh -Lport:localhost:port login@server2 mysql -u username -p --socket=/data/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

From `man ssh`:

> ```
>  -t      Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t
>          options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.
> ```